# \mathds from dsfont package works with latex and not with htlatex

Tags: math-mode, fonts, htlatex

When using `dsfont` package with latex, rendering is fine :

```
\usepackage{dsfont}
$A\,\otimes\,\mathds{1}_{q}$
```

here the result :

[image: latex result]

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with `htlatex` :

[image: htlatex result]

I have also tried with :

```
$A\,\otimes\,\mathds{1}$$_{q}$
```

but problem remains.

I suspect the 2 possibilities with `dsfont` and `doublestroke` packages on my MacOS.X. Indeed, I get the 2 following paths while searching for `dsfont.sty` :

```
$ locate dsfont.sty

/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.24/LaTeXML/Package/dsfont.sty.ltxml
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/doublestroke/dsfont.sty
```

Anyone has ever got this issue and is there a solution to get `$\mathds{1}_{q}$` command with the same rendering as `latex`.

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is not caused by `tex4ht`, the math is rendered by MathJax. It seems that it doesn't support the `\mathds` command, so you need to provide some definition for MathJax. Moreover, it seems that it [doesn't support blackboard numbers](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/792), so you need to find another solution, like providing direct Unicode value for doublestroke one. This can be done using custom macro for this symbol.

Try this TeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\newcommand\dsone{\mathds{1}}
\begin{document}

$A\,\otimes\,\dsone_{q}$
\end{document}
```

The `dsone` can be defined in this way:

```
\RequirePackage{mathjax-latex-4ht}
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\unexpanded{<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({ 
        TeX: {Macros : {  mathlarger: ["{\\large \#1}",1], dsone: "\\unicode{x1D7D9}" }},
        "HTML-CSS": { mtextFontInherit: true }
});</script>}}}
\EndPreamble
```

This is the rendering:

[image]